# adding reflection to iCarousel

Tags: iphone, ios, carousel

I tried to add reflection to my icarousel. Firstly my code was like this and it was working wright.

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index     reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
UIButton* button = (UIButton *)view;
if (button == nil)
{
    //no button available to recycle, so create new one
    UIImage *image = [arrKitapKapaklari objectAtIndex:index];
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [button.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:50];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}


//set button label
[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

return button;
```

}

After changing, my code became like this:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(ReflectionView *)view
{


UIButton* button = nil;
if (button == nil)
{

   view = [[[ReflectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, 200.0f)] autorelease];
    //no button available to recycle, so create new one
    UIImage *image = [arrKitapKapaklari objectAtIndex:index];
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [button.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:50];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [view addSubview:button];
}



//set button label
[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[view update];
return view;
```

}

Reflection appears. But the problem is when i move the carousel view, images not flowing correctly. Sometimes another carousel view appears.

Do you have any idea what causes that?

Comment: Why are you setting `button = nil;` before then having `if (button == nil)` ? You're never going to run the code in that block.

Comment: Actually he's *always* going to run it - but it's still wrong - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Code should be:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(ReflectionView *)view
{


UIButton* button = nil;
if (view == nil)
{
        //no view available to recycle, so create new one
    view = [[[ReflectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, 200.0f)] autorelease];

    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = view.bounds;
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [button.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:50];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            button.tag = 99;
        [view addSubview:button];
}
else
{
    button = (UIButton *)[view viewWithTag:99];
}

//set button label
[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIImage *image = [arrKitapKapaklari objectAtIndex:index];
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[view update];
return view;
}
```

Comment: sorry it didn't work. maybe i should explain clearly. firstly i add images to array called arrKitapKapaklari. And then i replace them with images i get from a webservice. And the problem is there. images have shadows when they flow. If i don't create a reflection view it works correctly. But i need reflection. I think the problem occurs when it try add subview. It seems like double view. And i am sorry for my terrible english. Thank you..

Comment: I've updated my answer. I don't think you've understood the whole re-using mechanism. It works like a table view - anything in the if (view == nil) part only happens once, so anything that needs to be updated each time the view is displayed has to go outside the if statement. The background loading thing is a separate problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use images with reflection built in them... don't need to do anything in code that way.. :p

Comment: but the thing is i am getting the images from a web service. so i don't know how to populate dynamic images with reflection

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I am loading images here:
    -(void) getImagesWithThread{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool;
    pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

```
//for(int i=0;i<bookCount;i++){
for(int i=0;i<bookCount;i++){   

    NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:      [arrBookImages objectAtIndex:i]]];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageWithData: imageData] retain];

    image = [self scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(140, 200) withImage:image];

    if(image!=nil) [arrBookImages replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:image];



    [image release]; }
```

[carousel reloadData];

[pool drain];

}
When i performed this in background it didn't reload correctly. İf i  perform normally, it works. But i want to load them in a thread. I mean first i want to set images and replace them images from url. but i want them to appear one by one. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes, when you've loaded a new image, you need to update the appropriate item in the carousel. I suggest calling [carousel reloaditemAtIndex:animated:] each time you load an image in the background. Make sure you call that on the main thread though because it's not safe to update the UI on a background thread. You can use performSelectorOnMainThread to call updates on the main thread from a backgroun thread. I'll add a background loading example to the next release of iCarousel as this is a common question.